# Count frequency distribution of monomial

Tags: distributions, multinomial-distribution, frequency

If you sample $N$ times from a set of $n$ objects with replacement and then plot the frequency against the count (i.e. the number of times an object has been chosen once, twice,...), you get a distribution.

Two questions.

1. If each of the $n$ objects has the same probability of being sampled, does that lead to a known distribution? For $N>>n$ it should narrow to a $\delta$-distribution around $N/n$ but what should it be for smaller $N$?
2. If you have such a sample frequency distribution, what test could you apply to it to determine whether the $n$ objects indeed had the same probability of being sampled?

Note that a [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359600/distribution-of-number-of-objects-in-simple-random-sampling-with-replacement-sr) asked about the distribution of the number of different objects.

Comment: What is $δ$ -distribution?

Comment: [Delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)

Answer (score 0):

Let assume there be no duplicates among $n$ subjects, and they have id numbers $1,2,..,n$. Let $X_i = x$ be the result of $i$-th sampling, $i=1,..., N$, $x=1,...,n$ and $Y_j$ be frequency of $j$ appeared in the sample after $N$ samplings.

1. Then, $X_i \sim $ discrete uniform distribution on $(1,2,..,n)$ for $i=1,...,N$.
   $$(Y_1,...,Y_n) \sim \mathrm{Multinomial}(N,1/n,...,1/n)$$

Then their distribution has no relation with $n/N$.

2. The Chi-square goodness-of-fit test can be used to test if $(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ come from a specified multinomial distribution. Theoretically, the exact test can be performed, but if $N$ and/or $n$ is large, it is still hard to finish the computation.